# How to declare an array in SQL server query and how to assign value into this array from other select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[createTimeFrameReport]

AS
--BEGIN TRAN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--declare @currentYear varchar (4)
--declare @currentMonth varchar(3)
--declare @currentDay varchar(3)
DECLARE @applicationNo varchar(20);

TYPE ListofIDs IS VARRAY(100) OF NUMBER;


//how to assign value for below code a.APPLICATION_ID into an array
SELECT @ListofIDs =a.APPLICATION_ID from BPM_PROCESS_INSTANCE a,BPM_TASK_INSTANCE b,BPM_PROCESS c where b.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID=a.ID and c.ID=a.TYPE_ID  and a.TYPE_ID=42 
AND b.ASSIGNED_ROLE IN('IDB_Reviewer','IFP_TechReviewerPermitting','IFP_ProcessManager','IFP_TechReviewerAssessment')

select @ListofIDs
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL there is not Array variable, however some SQL features replaces the logic of that array, it depend on how you use it, and i think what you are looking for is **Temporary Tables**

how to create temporary tables ? , to create temp table you need to have a hashtag sign **#** before the name of the temp table. see sample below (2 ways to create temp table

- Using **CREATE TABLE**

  ```
  CREATE TABLE #testTempTable
     (
       Column1 DataType,
       Column2 DataType,
       Column3 DataType,
       etc...
     )
  ```
- Using **SELECT INTO #testTempTable**

  ```
  SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
  INTO #testTempTable
  FROM SourceTableNameHere
  ```

There is also called **Variable Table** in SQL , you can google it to know how to use it.

**NOTE:** it is best practice to drop the temporary table at the end of the script to avoid errors when the script contains temp table runs in the 2nd time.

sytanx:

```
    DROP TABLE #testTempTable
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Server` has not array type but you can use table variables or temp tables instead.

Also please don't use outdated comma syntax, use `JOIN ON` instead.

**TEMP TABLE:**

```
SELECT a.APPLICATION_ID 
INTO #ListofIDs
FROM BPM_PROCESS_INSTANCE a
JOIN BPM_TASK_INSTANCE b
  ON b.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = a.ID 
JOIN BPM_PROCESS c
  ON c.ID = a.TYPE_ID  
WHERE a.TYPE_ID = 42 
  AND b.ASSIGNED_ROLE IN('IDB_Reviewer',
                         'IFP_TechReviewerPermitting',
                         'IFP_ProcessManager',
                         'IFP_TechReviewerAssessment');

SELECT #ListofIDs;
```

**TABLE VARIABLE:**

```
DECLARE @ListofIDs TABLE 
(
  APPLICATION_ID int
);

INSERT INTO @ListofIDs(APPLICATION_ID)
SELECT a.APPLICATION_ID 
FROM BPM_PROCESS_INSTANCE a
JOIN BPM_TASK_INSTANCE b
  ON b.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = a.ID 
JOIN BPM_PROCESS c
  ON c.ID = a.TYPE_ID  
WHERE a.TYPE_ID = 42 
  AND b.ASSIGNED_ROLE IN('IDB_Reviewer',
                         'IFP_TechReviewerPermitting',
                         'IFP_ProcessManager',
                         'IFP_TechReviewerAssessment');

SELECT @ListofIDs;
```